# Set-ADuser and problem with "user must change password on next logon"

Tags: powershell

:) I have a question. I am learning powershell and writing initial scripts. I want to write a script to check if a user is in a domain. Then I want this user account to check "user must change password on next logon" and at the same time I want to uncheck this later. In case the user is not in the domain, I want a message to be displayed that there is no account in AD.

I wrote the following script which doesn't quite work.... While the script finds the correctly entered account in AD without any problem, if it enters an incorrect login, I get the message "Set-ADUser : Cannot find object with identity: "test" in DC=xx, DC=xx". This is not what I would like to see displayed, in the case of an incorrectly entered login. Is the problem a badly written if statement?

Thank you for your help.

View my code:

```
$User = Read-Host "Enter user login: "
if($User)
{
    Write-Verbose "Searching user..." -Verbose
    Set-ADUser -Identity $User -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true

    if($true)
    {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $User -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false
   
    get-aduser -identity $User -properties * | 
    select accountexpirationdate, accountexpires, accountlockouttime, badlogoncount, padpwdcount, lastbadpasswordattempt, lastlogondate, lockedout, passwordexpired, passwordlastset, pwdlastset | 
    format-list

    Write-Verbose "Password extended!" -Verbose
    }
}

else
{
     echo "User doesn't exist!"
}pause
```

Comment: `if($true)` makes no sense at all.. Why first set the `ChangePasswordAtLogon` to $true and later to $false without knowing what it was in the first place? If you want to check if a user exists just use `Get-ADUser`. Also don't use `-Properties *`, only list the properties you need and that aren't returned by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Try/Catch" with exception message to avoid throwing an error in case the user account doesn't exist in the AD.

```
$User = Read-Host "Enter user login"

If ($User)
{
    Write-Host "Searching User $User..."

    Try
    {
        Get-ADUser -Identity $User
        Set-ADUser -Identity $User -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True
    }
    Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityResolutionException]
    {
        Write-Host "User account $User does not exist."
    }
}
Else
{
    Write-Host "Username is empty."
}
```

Also, you don't have to uncheck the "Password must change at the next logon" later because you only check it if the user exists.